# How to form DateTime with proper value from two strings after concatenation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

How do I form the DateTime with the proper value from two strings? For example, I have a textbox for the date with input like '06/25/2014' & another textbox for the time with input like '23:59'. I am trying to concatenate these two textbox values to form a DateTime variable with value of combined result as '2014-06-25 23:59:00.000'

I have written this code but get this error:

`String was not recognized as a valid DateTime`

```
string StartDate = Convert.ToString(txtOffBarDate.Text);
string StartTime =Convert.ToString(txtOffbarTime.Text);

DateTime StartDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate + " " + StartTime);
```

Comment: What is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: How To know The CurrentCulture Info?

Comment: You can check the value of [`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime startDateTime =DateTime.Parse(string.Format("{0} {1}",txtOffBarDate.Text,txtOffbarTime.Text),yourCultureInfo);
```

**EDIT**

To populate yourCultureInfo: CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");

Comment: My Input Value was '06/25/2014' & '23:59' But
Still getting this in StartDateTime {01-Jan-01 12:00:00 AM} & with the same error.


but i did not provide any CultureInfo. How to give CaltureInfo?

Comment: thanks ! it Worked after  putting the cultureInfo :)

Answer (score 1):

[`Convert.ToDateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method uses standard date and time patterns of your current thread culture.

Looks like `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff` is not standard date and time format for your [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You can use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.TryParseExact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods to parse your [custom date and time string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Here an example on [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/);

```
string s = "2014-06-25 23:59:00.000";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", 
                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    dt.Dump();
}
```

Next time, if you have a question about globalization issues, please provide your `CurrentCulture` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
DateTime StartDateTime ;
DateTime.TryParse(StartDate + " " + StartTime,out StartDateTime );
```

Comment: `TryParse` method doesn't return a `DateTime`, it returns a `boolean` value.

Comment: Oh yes. I missed that. Silly mistake. Thanks @SonerGönül